# Twitter API - Reply to a retweet

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, codeigniter-2

I am writing a little twitter API (using [Elliot Haughin's library](https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-twitter)) and I want to reply to a retweet that the app posts.

I have read the docs for [statues/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update), and have tried using '*in_reply_to_status_id*' with the value taken from '*user_mentions*', but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong, or is there a better way to do it?

Code sample;

```
$answer = '@'.$retweet->entities->user_mentions[0]->screen_name.' thanks!!';
$this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update', array('status' => $answer, 'in_reply_to_status_id' => $retweet->id));
```

Comment: Can you give me the tutorial how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the name of the user who retweeted the post, and not the one that was mentioned in the post.

```
$answer = '@'.$retweet->user->screen_name.' thanks!!';
```

Of cource, for this to work, you should request the tweets with `include_entities => 1`

Comment: My search has 'include_entities' set to 1, but there isn't 'user->screen_name', but 'from_user' works. Thanks.